# Command Line/Window in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am new to Visual Studio Code and using the latest Version: 1.29.1.

In Matlab I had a script window where I wrote code, a Command Window where I could test both snippets of code and enter variables to see their value, and I had a workspace view that listed all of my variables, their types, and their values.

In Visual Studio Code, I see the obvious script writing window, but where is the command window to test run code and run variables to see their value, and the workspace window where variable values are displayed?

Thanks Community

Answer (score 1):

You get to the terminal with CTRL`

You can also double tap the shift key and type "terminal" and that should work too.

Here are the docs:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: Thanks much Randy, but I am probably asking the wrong question. I am coding with Javascript. The "Terminal Window" gives me the C prompt which I cannot run and test Javascript code snippets, nor can I test declared Javascript variables for their values. And the Terminal window does not give me a list of all my variables, their types, and their values. There is a Variable window, but when I run javascript from the script window the declared variables do not pop up in that window as I would expect.

Comment: I have answered the question posed. If your question is about debugging javascript then you should ask another question or edit the question to it reflects your _real_ question.

Comment: I have the following snippet of Javascript that I want to test run:

<script>
                var nm = prompt("What is your name?");
                document.write(nm);
</script>

I have the following snippet of Javascript:

<script>
                var nm = prompt("What is your name?");
                document.write(nm);
</script>

1. Where in vscode can I run this snippet? The terminal I get is a command prompt that does not recognize Javascript. 

2. Where in vscode can I run-test the variable nm?

3. Where is the variable listed  with its value and type?

Comment: I would kindly like to hear from another person if they can please tell me where I can test-run javascript snippets and where I can see the value and type of all my declared variables. Thanks in advance.